# Why does my Python Executable file print its commands list every time a command is entered instead of executing a command?

Tags: python, output, pyinstaller, executable, execution

I am presently making a executable file using Python code and compiling it with PyInstaller. I have tesetd my Python code and made sure to not find any errors or accidental loops. Despite this the result of my executable file is that instead of executing a command when a user inputs a number, the program prints the list of available commands again.

The list of modules I am using is datetime, time, json, os, multiprocessing, sys, socket, urllib.request, BeautifulSoup.

Below is images of my programs UI through Visual Studio Code of which works fine, and then the executable file is shown next printing the list of commands over again when it shouldn't:

[Example of Python code on startup in Visual Studio Code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mezq5.png)

[Example of Python code executing command 9 in Visual Studio Code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjisZ.png)

[Example of Python executable file on startup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quDUv.png)

[Example of Python executable file executing command 9.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4RaI.png)

I cannot for the life of me understand what is happening and I do hope someone may have an explanation as to what I am doing wrong. Also if you have any questions for more context feel free to ask. Thanks!